# Rock Paper Scissors score keeps resetting

Tags: python

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game with a pointing system and it seems to always give me a value of zero every time the scores are revealed. Help is appreciated.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def play():
    player = input("Which will you choose? Rock, Paper or Scissors? Type 'E' to exit ")

    elements = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    cpu = random.choice(elements)

    scoreplayer = 0

    scorecpu = 0 

    if player.lower() == cpu:
        print("This is a tie, no one scores a point")
        play()

    elif player.lower() == "rock":
        if cpu == "paper":
            print("Paper beats Rock, CPU gains 1 point")
            scorecpu = scorecpu + 1
            play()
        elif cpu == "scissors":
            print("Rock beats Scissors, you gain 1 point")
            scoreplayer = scoreplayer + 1
            play()

    elif player.lower() == "paper":
        if cpu == "scissors":
            print("Scissors beats Paper, CPU gains 1 point")
            scorecpu = scorecpu + 1
            play()
        elif cpu == "rock":
            print("Paper Beats Rock, you gain 1 point")
            scoreplayer = scoreplayer + 1
            play()

    elif player == "scissors":
        if cpu == "rock":
            print("Rock beats Scissors, CPU gains 1 point")
            scorecpu = scorecpu + 1
            play()
        elif cpu == "paper":
            print("Scissors beats Paper, you gain 1 point")
            scoreplayer = scoreplayer + 1
            play()

    elif player.lower() == "e":
        print("")
        print("You have " + str(scoreplayer) + " points")
        print("")
        print("CPU has " + str(scorecpu) + " points")
        sys.exit()

    else:
        play()
```

Answer (score 2):

`scoreplayer = 0` and the other assignment are running every time `play` is called, which creates new variables with values of 0 each time. Pass the current scores as arguments to `play` instead:

```
def play(scoreplayer, scorecpu):
   # Get rid of these lines
   # scoreplayer = 0
   # scorecpu = 0 

   . . .
   # Update the scores here

   else:
        play(scoreplayer, scorecpu)


play(0, 0) # Start with scores of 0
```

Or switch to using a loop construct like `while` from recursion and update the scores within the loop. In a language like Python, recursion isn't really suitable here anyways.

Answer (score 0):

because you're setting your variables in your function it will by definition be reset each time it runs. like @Carcigenicate said you could pass them as arguments to it or 
use a while loop but you might also want to look into the global statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you're resetting the score every time you call the play() function.
A solution to your problem is to make your score variable a global variable

```
scoreplayer = 0
scorecpu = 0 

def play():
    player = input("Which will you choose? Rock, Paper or Scissors? Type 'E' to exit ")

    elements = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    cpu = random.choice(elements)

    global scoreplayer
    global scorecpu

    # rest of your code

play()
```

When defining variables outside of functions we can access them by using the global keyword

You can read more about the global keyword here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword